# Check in client side if a socket.io id is still connected

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I would like to check in client side if a socket id is still connected.

The version of `socket.io` I use is `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`.

I have tried answers in several threads, but it did not work.

**Edit 1:** Actually, I have 1 server which can serve many clients. In the server I have the following code which sends the socket id to a client when it is connected:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("LOG: just connected: " + socket.id);    
  socket.emit('id', socket.id);    
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log("LOG: just disconnected: " + socket.id)
  })
})
```

Two clients may talk to each other via the server, that's why `ClientA` may (besides its own socket id) keep the socket id of `ClientB`. Thus, it will be useful for me to check (from an id) in the client-side if a client is still connected. It will be OK if this check needs to ask the server, I just want this check to be as simple and sure as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently (from your comments), clientA has a `socket.id` of clientB and clientA wants to know if clientB is currently connected.  Since a `socket.id` is just a string value, there is no way for clientA to tell from just the `socket.id` if clientB is connected or not.  That information would have to come from the server.

You can have clientA ask the server if it thinks clientB is connected (by sending the socket.id of clientB to the server in a request message) and the server could respond with what it knows about clientB's connected state.

The server maintains a list of all connected clients.  One of the ways you can access that list is via a map that is indexed by `socket.id`.  So, it would be easy for the server to see if a connected client is in the map with a given socket.id.

Here's a way you could ask your server if a given socket.id is connected.  This would be your server code:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("LOG: just connected: " + socket.id);    
  socket.emit('id', socket.id);    
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log("LOG: just disconnected: " + socket.id)
  })

  // use the ack function argument to send a response back
  socket.on('isConnected', function(id, ackFn) {
      let otherSocket = io.sockets.connected[id];
      ackFn(!!otherSocket && otherSocket.connected);
  });
});
```

And, the client would send a request and listen for the response:

```
socket.emit('isConnected', someId, function(result) {
    console.log(someId + ": " + result ? "is connected" : "is not connected");
});
```

---

**Original answer that thought you were asking how a client can tell if its own socket is connected.**

A socket.io object has a `.connected` property that reflects what socket.io thinks is the current state of the connection.

```
 if (socket.connected) {
     // socket.io thinks it is still connected
 }
```

You can see it being used here [internally in the `.emit()` method](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L153):

```
if (this.connected) {
  this.packet(packet);
} else {
  this.sendBuffer.push(packet);
}
```

Socket.io already implements its own heartbeat sent from server to client so it will usually notice when the connection stops working.  By default, it will try to reconnect, but if that reconnection does not work immediately, the socket may remain in the disconnected state while it retries further reconnects.

Comment: What if i only have the socket id rather than the socket object?

Comment: @SoftTimur - `socket.id` is a server-side thing, but your code is client-side.  I'm very confused.  You will need to get the client-side `socket` object to use this flag.  If you want further help, will have to show a lot more code.  I've answer the specific question you asked.  What you're asking now is something else.  If you have a `socket.id` of some other client and you want to know if that client is connected, that's a whole different question and you should probably start a new question and fully explain what you're trying to do including showing all relevant code.

Comment: My initial question is about **id**, thougth it is indeed from the server side. I am not saying we should not ask server to check the connection state. I will show more code when i have my PC.

Comment: @SoftTimur -  Your question is certainly not clear.  Are you now saying that in clientA, you want to know if clientB is currently connected?  If that's the question, then you better edit your question to actually ask that.  And, I'll give you a hint.  You will have to ask the server whether it thinks clientB is connected.  A given socket.io client only knows about it's own connected state.

Comment: One last question, if I want to make a function `isConnected(socketId)`, it still needs to be asynchronous, right?

Comment: @SoftTimur - Yes, talking to your server is always an asynchronous operation to get live data from the server.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest sending a broadcast every 30 sec or so, This way you won't loose connection to your socket.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    yoursocket.emit('broadcast');
}, 30000 /* 30 sec */);
```

Comment: I am not trying to avoid disconnection (I may close a connection myself), I just want to check if an id is still connected.

Comment: you will receive an error if it is no, this way you will know,.

Comment: It is quite odd that there is no direct way to check that in real time...

Comment: socket.io already uses its own heartbeat packets.  There is no need to repeat that.